# How to reset code formatting with Uncrustify

Tags: c++, formatting, uncrustify

I am using [Uncrustify](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify) to formatting my C++ code and I am making some *experiments* with infinite list of settings.

Because of some bad settings my code now has a lot of new line that split statement in more lines (mostly due to a short line width).

I would like to reformat the code in order to have one statement per line and reformat it in another way.

How can I do it?

Comment: I suppose `git checkout -- .` (or however your SCM spells "throw away all changes") is going to help?

Comment: Sadly I made some commits (on SVN) after uncrustify execution.

Comment: Ah!  You do *have* an SCM then.  I'd a) get a listing of the diffs that you made after the uncrustify checkin; b) revert back to before you started; c) reapply the diffs (probably by hand).

Comment: Unfortunately we made a lot of commits and now we realized that our uncrustify configuration is not ok, reverting to a _stable_ situation would mean to merge manually a lot of diffs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no undo function in Uncrustify and if your SCM can not help you, you are unfortunately out of luck.

Regarding to the newlines, which seem to cause the most problems for you, you could try to remove and reapply them with the 'nl_remove_extra_newlines' option (see a short discussion about it in the uncrustify issue [#994](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify/issues/994)) in combination with other options that are influencing newlines.